# Navigating forms using HTML?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

is there a way to navigate to another form using HTML ?

for example, a link in side my innerHTML

```
<a href="goto form 2 here">Form2</a>
```

it is just HTML i was hardcoding into the innerHTML property of a TW3ScrollControl. Some of the HTML is static, some is dynamic data (e.g. question & answer) I get from my JSON file

for example

```
Who is  the president of the United States?


     Hillary Clinton
     Bernie Sanders
     Joseph Biden
     Donald Trump
```

so, giving something like this off the top of my head, how would on do a GotoForm if one of these names were clicked?

```
<div> 
    <p>Who is  the president of the United States?</p>
    <br>
    <center>
     <A href=""> Hillary Clinton </A><br>
     <A href=""> Bernie Sanders </A<br>
     <A href=""> Joseph Biden </A<br>
     <A href=""> Donald Trump </A<br>
    </center>
</div>
```

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a little help from facebook friend :) I was able to come up with the following

```
var i: integer;
      IdStr: String;
begin
 fQuestion.content.InnerHTML:= '<div style="text-align: center; position: relative;">' +
  '<br><center><p>' + fQuestions.questions[fIndex].question + '</p></center><br>' +
   '<center>' +
     '<A id="answer1" href="">' + fQuestions.questions[fIndex].answers[0] + '</A><br>' +
     '<A id="answer2" href="">' + fQuestions.questions[fIndex].answers[1] + '</A><br>' +
     '<A id="answer3" href="">' + fQuestions.questions[fIndex].answers[2] + '</A><br>' +
     '<A id="answer4" href="">' + fQuestions.questions[fIndex].answers[3] + '</A><br>' +
    '</center>' +
  '</div>';


  for i:= 1 to 4 do
  begin
   IdStr:= 'answer' + intToStr(i);
    var h:= BrowserAPI.Document.getElementById(idStr);
    if (h) then
    begin
     h.onclick := procedure (ev: variant)
     begin
       //do something here
     end;
    end;
 end;
end;
```